# How to make an interactive command in discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am wondering how in discord.js to make an interactive giveaway command like the giveaway bot.
For example: >gcreate, it starts an interactive setup to a giveaway.

Comment: You are expected to research and attempt this, this site serves to help you debug existing code and or point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Message Collectors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html) from the **discord.js** guide and similarly there exist reaction collectors for the giveaway commands or you can resort to packages like [discord-giveaways](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-giveaways)

Here is an example showing how to setup a giveaway

```js
const prefix = '>g'
const { GiveawaysManager } = require('discord-giveaways');
// Starts updating currents giveaways
const manager = new GiveawaysManager(client, {
    storage: './giveaways.json',
    updateCountdownEvery: 10000,
    hasGuildMembersIntent: false,
    default: {
        botsCanWin: false,
        exemptPermissions: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES', 'ADMINISTRATOR'],
        embedColor: '#FF0000',
        reaction: ''
    }
});
// We now have a giveawaysManager property to access the manager everywhere!
client.giveawaysManager = manager;

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("I'm ready !");
});


client.on('message', (message) => {
    const ms = require('ms'); // npm install ms
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'create') {
        // g!start-giveaway 2d 1 Awesome prize!
        // will create a giveaway with a duration of two days, with one winner and the prize will be "Awesome prize!"

        client.giveawaysManager.start(message.channel, {
            time: ms(args[0]),
            prize: args.slice(2).join(' '),
            winnerCount: parseInt(args[1])
        })
    });
        // This would start the giveaway
    }
});
client.login('TOKEN_HERE');
```